# Why would I use \dimexpr .. \relax in \setlength?

Tags: lengths, setlength

I read somewhere that you should use `\dimexpr ... \relax` when defining lengths.

Is that really the case? There seems to be no difference between using it or not:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength{\onelen}
\newlength{\twolen}
\newlength{\threelen}

\setlength{\threelen}{5em}

\setlength{\onelen}{2.5\threelen}
\setlength{\twolen}{\dimexpr2.5\threelen\relax}

\begin{document}
    a \hspace{\onelen} b
    
    c \hspace{\twolen} d
\end{document}
```

Are there specific circumstances where you should use it or can you skip it and make the length more readable?

Comment: @mrCarnivore Additions are possible without `\dimexpr`, but this requires to load package [calc](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/calc) that redefines `\setlength` to support some simple arithmetic.

Comment: `\dimexpr … \relax` does not make sense in your example. But if you have something like `\newcommand*{\foo}[1]{…\setlength{\bar}{#1}…}` you could add extra functionality using `\dimexpr #1\relax` — if you want and if it makes sense. See [the eTeX manual](https://texdoc.org/serve/etex/0) section 3.5 for more information about `\dimexpr`, `\numexpr` and `\glueexpr`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax `<factor><internal dimen>` or `<factor><internal glue>` for a dimen value is supported by classical TeX, see TeXbook pages 269-271. Because `<factor>` can be decimal constant and `<internal glue>` can be a token declared by `\skipdef` primitive, the following example is valid in classical TeX:

```
\newskip\twolen
\newskip\threelen  \threelen=5em\relax

\twolen=2.5\threelen \relax
```

This is an extraction of your example, because the LaTeX macro `\newlength` does `\neswkip` and this macro does `\skipdef`, so the declared token is "skipdef token" from TeXbook's point of view. The `<factor>` is `2.5` here and `<internal glue>` is `\threelen`. Because `\threelen` was set to 5em, the resulting assignment to `\twolen` is 2.5*5em = 12.5em.

We can interpret the `\threelen` as "a declared unit" of measure and read the syntax `2.5\threelen` as `<factor>`*`<unit>`.

Classical TeX supports no more calculation with dimen values, only the mentioned `<factor>`*`<unit>`.

eTeX gives a new primitive `\dimexpr <dimen expression> <optional relax>` which allows to do more dimen calculations, like `2em-4ex+.5\hsize`.

The accepted answer here doesn't explain why the "puzzling error message" occurs here. The example does, in fact:

```
\newskip\test

\test=\dimexpr 3pt+1cm\relax plus something else
```

The `\dimexpr` primitive creates a `<dimen>` value and consumes the `\relax` expanded from LaTeX macro `\setlength`. So, we get

```
\test=<dimen value> plus something else
```

Because `\test` was declared as `\newskip` (i.e. using `\skipdef` primitive), the assignment has syntax

```
\test <optional equal> <dimen> <optional plus followed by stretch value> <optional minus followed by shrink value>
```

If there is no `plus` after the `<dimen>`, the assignment is finalized with zero stretch value. But we have `plus` here in egreg's example, then TeX excepts the `<stretch value>` which must begin by `<number>`. The number isn't present here, so TeX reports `missing number` error.

Answer (score 11):

Look at the definition of `\setlength`

```
% latex.ltx, line 7668:
\def\setlength#1#2{#1 #2\relax}
```

Now let's try

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength{\test}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\test}{\dimexpr 3pt+1cm} plus something else

\end{document}
```

This will issue the puzzling error message

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   s
l.7 \setlength{\test}{\dimexpr 3pt+1cm} plus s
                                              omething else
```

Always use `\relax` to end `\dimexpr`, unless you are 100% sure that you can omit it.

It would be the same with your

```
\setlength{\twolen}{\dimexpr2.5\threelen}
```

if something like `plus` or `minus` follows. By the way,

```
\setlength{\onelen}{2.5\threelen}
```

is way more efficient and will not run into the problem described above.

Comment: So \relax is necessary (when using additions and therefore needing \dimexpr) but if you are only using multiplication then you can (and should) leave out \dimexpr and \relax?